# Is this property loss avoidable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` which is presented in a `UINavigationController` (it is the topmost visible view in the stack). My `UIViewController` maintains a set of child views which all have weak references up to the parent view controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) RDCustomViewController *customParentViewController;
```

(For argument sake, please ignore the fact that `UIViewController` already has a `parentViewController` property.) I am receiving some rare crash reports which lead me to believe that this property becomes nil at some point. This must be impossible since the only time the object would become released is when it is no longer visible by the `UINavigationController` (and therefore all the children would be deallocated by this stage too).

Before going and rolling a different implementation to get the same functionality, can anyone think of what might be causing this?